# Quais são os reais problemas para quem trabalha com desenvolvimento em assembly?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, assembly, arquitetura-computadores, mips

Estou estudando a arquitetura e implementação em MIPS, mas como não trabalho em baixo nível o que estou realizando são exercícios iniciais básicos em qualquer inicio de aprendizado, gostaria de saber é quais são as dificuldades e problemas reais de um desenvolvedor em assembly?!

Por exemplo para um desenvolvimento de sistemas embarcados.

Answer (score 5):

Os principais problemas são:

1) O trabalho rende muito pouco, porque cada instrução assembly faz muito pouco.

2) Estruturas de controle são escassas, você basicamente tem "Jump" e nada mais.

3) O desenvolvedor terá de decorar um compêndio de instruções que só se aplica a um processador, às vezes se aplicam apenas a uma faixa de modelos, então é um conhecimento que fica obsoleto rápido.

4) A portabilidade é comprometida; copiar código de outro projeto que envolva outra arquitetura é complicado.

5) Em tese um programa escrito em assembly é mais rápido que qualquer outro, mas isto pode deixar de ser verdade com novos modelos de processadores, em que seu programa ainda funciona mas as instruções não funcionam mais do mesmo jeito que antes; quem escreve compiladores fica sabendo disso bem antes do processador chegar no mercado.

Usar assembler ainda faz sentido para acessar instruções especiais, que os compiladores não aproveitam. É o caso de algumas otimizações matemáticas, controladores DSP, criptografia acelerada no hardware, etc.